# Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: hamilton_filter.pyx

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to implement the markov regime switch model in python, and I found this https://github.com/ChadFulton/pymar. But when I try to compile it, I get the message

```
Compiling hamilton_filter.pyx because it changed.
Cythonizing hamilton_filter.pyx

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
import numpy as np
^
------------------------------------------------------------

hamilton_filter.pyx:1:0: 'pymar-master.mar_c.hamilton_filter' is not a valid module name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    ext_modules = cythonize(ext_modules),
  File "/home/xinzhou/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython-0.22-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 865, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args[1:])
  File "/home/xinzhou/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython-0.22-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 985, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: hamilton_filter.pyx
```

anyone knows how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking deeper in the code of Cython, it looks like cython does not like at all names containing a dash `-`. The dash however is created by `pip`. In this specific case, you cannot just pip the repository, you have to clone/download it and run the command as explained on the README of the repository.